# What direction do arrays go in TA-lib? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, ta-lib

I am wondering about which direction to input my arrays and which direction I should be taking them as the output using the TA-lib nuget package in C#

```
float[] closeVals; //Price close values, most recent close is the last index
double[] rsiVals = new double[closeVals.Count]; // Empty output array
var retCode = Core.Rsi(0, lastIdx, closeVals, int period = 14, out int outBegIdx, out int outNBElement, rsiVals);
foreach (double item in rsiVals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

My output array rsiVals is seemingly coming out in reverse (ending with fourteen 0s, starting with values around 50-60). Does this mean I need to put my close values in reversed starting with the most recent close price first or does the algorithm just output in reverse?

Comment: What do the `outBegIdx`,`outNBElement` show? Most likely they are the starting index of the results in the output buffer and number of outputs. BTW calling `.ToArray()` on an array creates a copy of the original. That's a waste of memory unless cloning is what you really want.

Comment: The ToArray() is called because in my actual code I am using a List type I shall edit appropriately. outBegIdx show the beginning index after the inital zeros and outNBElement shows the number of elements that are not the initial 0 values in this case outBegIdx = 13 and outNBElement is (length of rsiVals) - period

Comment: Which means there's no problem, since the results do start after the 14th array element. Instead of `foreach(double item in rsiVals)` you should have used `(for int i=outBegIdx,i<outBegIdx+outNBElement;i++){...}`. Check the documentation for that function

Comment: That isn't the issue. The issue is whether the close prices are going in end first or beginning first. The array starting after the 14th element will happen regardless of which way round the close prices are input. I have tried checking the documentation but its only well documented for c++ and doesn't specify whether arrays are supposed to be input newest or oldest value first

Comment: I have c++ experience with TA-Lib. Close price MUST be in historical order. outNBElement returns number of results in rsiVals. It can be less then `closeVals.Count` bcs rolling indicators that computed based on N days could be calculated starting N+1 day only. So you get Count-N results. The results are put in rsiVals starting from 0 element always. outBegIdx is informative index which describe witch day in input array the 0 element in results array is really corresponding for. Most probably you're misunderstanding your results and have trash values in result array after outNBElement in it.

Comment: Each indicator have a *Lookback() function which tells you the number of input elements that are required for indicator to start output anything for given input params (period etc.). Let it be X. You always getting back `closeVals.Count-X` results or nothing if `closeVals.Count < X`. The *Lookback() functions allow you to know the result array size beforehand and allocate exact number of elements for it before calling real indicator func. You may use this. But X can't be negative so you may use `closeVals.Count` size whcih always enough just don't process trash values at results end.